# Load images in recyclerview dynamically from ArrayList

Tags: java, android

In my application, I define an ArrayList whose default element is empty.

Then the user can dynamically select image files or take photos and then the results will be accommodated to those ArrayList.

The problem is that the ArrayList that already contains these elements is displayed to RecylerView with CardView to be unresponsive. If you scroll up or down, there is a delay.

I really appreciate all the help.

**Activity**

```
private ArrayList<Image> images = new ArrayList<>();
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
private Uri mCapturedImageURI;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

public class IncomingLokalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_incoming_lokal);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_list_view);
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, images);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) { //taken from camera
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor =
                    managedQuery(mCapturedImageURI, projection, null,
                            null, null);
            int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

            preparedObjectDataImage("_file", "Taken From Camera", picturePath);

        } else if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) { //taken from gallery

            DzilFileHelper dzilFileHelper = new DzilFileHelper();

            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount(); //evaluate the count before the for loop --- otherwise, the count is evaluated every loop.
                Cursor cursor;
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    Uri selectedImage;
                    selectedImage = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                    cursor = getContentResolver()
                            .query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null,
                                    null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    cursor.close();
                    preparedObjectDataImage("_file", "Taken From Gallery Multi", dzilFileHelper.getPathFromURI(this, selectedImage));
                }
            } else if (data.getData() != null) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                        .query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null,
                                null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                cursor.close();
                preparedObjectDataImage("_file", "Taken From Gallery", dzilFileHelper.getPathFromURI(this, selectedImage));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Handle Image Object**

```
private void preparedObjectDataImage(String title, String description, String picturePath) {
    Image image = new Image();
    image.setTitle(title);
    image.setDescription(description);
    image.setDatetime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    image.setPath(picturePath);
    images.add(image);
    imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // set new item to recylerview
}
```

In my Adapter, I also set the image to thumbnail format, but still not good when scrolling.

**Adapter**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageViewHolder> {

    Context c;
    ArrayList<Image> images;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Image> images) {
        this.c = c;
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.item_image, parent, false);
        return new ImageViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final int THUMBSIZE = 96;
        Image image = images.get(position);
        holder.nameTxt.setText(image.getPath());

        // Resize to thumbnail
        holder.img.setImageBitmap(ThumbnailUtils
                .extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getPath()),
                        THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return images.size();
    }
}
```

**The holder**

```
public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView nameTxt;
    ImageView img;

    public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        nameTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_img_infor);
        img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_img_icon);

    }
}
```

Comment: Use an Image loader to load Thumbnail for You . It will Cache the result . The problem you are facing is because each time you are creating a `Bitmap` inside `onBindViewHolder` . Probably should use Glide or Picasso.

Answer (score 1):

Working well with Glide.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final Image image = images.get(position);
    holder.nameTxt.setText(image.getPath());

    //Handle to Glide
    Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(new File(image.getPath())).into(holder.img);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make your viewholder as a final

```
 final Holder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemlayoutforscheduledmeetings, null);
        holder = new Holder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);


    } else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }
```